# No schema show when logging into iam user via cloud sql proxy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

I'm logging into a cloudsql instance via the cloud sql proxy and an iam database user. The authentication succeeds, but doesn't show me any schema / resources or anything in MySQLWorkbench. It's just completely blank.

The iam user is a cloudsql admin, and an owner of the project, so it couldn't be a permission issue could it?

If I use a non iam user, and login with a standard database user and password, everything works fine, and as expected. What else could it be? This seems like something common that other people would have experienced as well.

Comment: Please edit your question and share a screenshot of your MySQLWorkbench. Also, provide the steps or a link that you follow that lead you to the blank screen.

Comment: When you use your IAM user, what are the permission of the user?

Answer (score 1):

When an IAM user is added to a database instance, that new user is granted no privileges on any databases, by default.

You need to use either the `root` or another privileged user and grant the appropriate database permissions to your IAM user.

For more information see: [Grant Database Privileges to an IAM user](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/add-manage-iam-users#grant-db-privileges)

Comment: This is unexpected, and if true, is likely the issue. @jack-wotherspoon if this is true, what are the cloudsql read and write roles for?